# cordova upload filetransfer returned html and file not uploaded

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cordova, upload

I seem to have run into a wall trying to upload photos to a server using Cordova (3.5) and Eclipse. I've checked my code several times and the person who has written the aspx service has checked things on their side. 
I'm using the filetransfer plugin and downloads are working perfectly so I'm guessing all is well in that regard. Heres the upload code:

```
function uploadImage(fileURL)
{
    var win = function (r) {
        alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        alert("Response = " + r.response);
        alert("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        alert("upload error source " + error.source);
        alert("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    checkFileSize("1410857789947.jpg");

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "myfile";
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

    alert(fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://cosmicorders.fusion-online.co.za/Services/Site/OrderService.asmx/saveFile"), win, fail, options);
}
```

I'm alerting the file size of the file at fileURL, the path is fine.

The server side code is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string saveFile()
        {
            string msg = "";
            try
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["myfile"];
                string saveFile = file.FileName;
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/LocationImages/" + saveFile));

                msg = "File uploaded";


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Could not upload file: " + ex.Message;

            }
            return msg;
        }
```

When ever the method is executed I get a response with html which seems to be an error page with a back button. Code 200 is returned from cordova and bytes send 98547. 
I don't understand how success is triggering, nothing has obviously been sent.

I've added a mistake to the server path:

ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://cosmicorders.fusion-online.co.za/Services/Site/OrderService.asmx/s**aveFilzz**"), win, fail, options);

And the results is the same: success code 200, same html response and bytes send

I checked my res/xml/config.xml has

Maybe someone with a better understanding of cordova or webservices can shine some light on this?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!